# Regex : Extract String from pipe sperated file

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

I have a raw http response as below :

```
1
1|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX|
|first
```

I need to extract 44001 portion from it.

I can uniquely identify this string using Start : |555   End : |

I have tried

```
(.*)(|555)(.*)(|)
```

which returns 1.

On the side note, I am using this regex in Jmeter which follows java script styled regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your regex that I can see at first glance:

The first is that the the pipe character has a special meaning in regex, it means OR.  So for example this regex:

```
[abc|def]
```

Will match 'abc' or 'def'.

This means that your regex sections '(|555)' and '(|)' mean 'nothing OR 555' for the first case, and 'nothing OR nothing' for the second case.

If you want to match the pipe character you need to escape it, so '|' becomes '\|'.

The second problem is that .* is a a greedy matcher, it will match as much as it can, and since your dot represents any character you will get a match right the way up to the next matching group.

So if we fix the pipe problem and get this new regex:

```
.*\|555(.*)\|
```

Using your example string, the .* matches:

```
1|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX|
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In other words, it matches as much as it can until the next group matches.

You can switch from greedy to lazy by adding an extra ? at the end, so '.*' becomes '.*?' this will stop matching as soon as a match is made, your regex is now:

```
.*\|555(.*?)\|
```

And your matching group now becomes:

```
1|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX|
                               ^^^^^
```

If you know that the characters following 555 will always be numerical digits, then you can restrict your matching group to just numbers, and not worry about greedy and lazy:

```
.*\|555([0-9]*)\|
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I select your answer as the correct answer for the in depth explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If that's the pattern, this will work:

```
\|555(\d+)\|
```

It matches the part after `555` and between two pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$str  = '11|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX||first ';
preg_match('/\|555(?P<digits>\d+)\|/',$str,$match);

echo $match['digits'];
```

OR

```
$str  = '11|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX||first ';
preg_match('/\|555(\d+)+\|/',$str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Your regex part is perfect. But the regex goes inside the jmeter, which cant handle the php code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` it would be faster

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "11|CI17438666|IB136180000001|55544001|10.106.1.XXX||first";
var pattern = "(.*)(/|555)([0-9]*)(/|)";
var result = str.match(pattern);
// The matches are in elements 0 through n.
for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++)
{
    document.write ("submatch " + index + ": " +  result[index]);
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

Third sub string will return the required result.